# Null pointer exception while dealing with spinners

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I am getting a null pointer exception when i am running this peice of code

```
            private void loadSpinnerData() {
        // database handler
        AttendAppDatasource db = new AttendAppDatasource(getApplicationContext());

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> clas = db.viewCol(AttendAppDbOpenHelper.COLUMN_CLASS);
        Log.i("Select Class","List Assigned");
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, clas);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

this is the relevant log output

[image]

this is the log out put corresponding to the list
[image]

Comment: Assuming that your spinner itself is actually null, since dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource() doesn't hit a npe

Comment: Please verify if db or clas variables are null

Comment: the closing paranthesis of this method

Comment: @carlosmaciel they aren't i updated the question check

Comment: @zgc7009 how can that be null?

Comment: @Denson: You don't show us where 'spinner' is assigned a value, or where its value might be nulled out. Also, we have no idea how the provided code snippet fits into the overall execution flow. So, even if you do assign a value to 'spinner' somewhere, maybe that is done *after* this code is called, or maybe 'spinner' is nulled out *before* this code is called.

Comment: If you don't set it to anything, or attempt to set it to something that is null, it will be null. We don't see anywhere that you actually set your spinner

Comment: yes the error is solved 
i was setting the value of the spinner in the oncreate method is  why the spinner was null
thank you for ypur help

Comment: @zgc7009, post your comment as an answer, you were right about this problem ;)

Comment: @zgc7009 yeah please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spinner is set to null. You need to get it from your resources

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.'spinner_id_name');
```

Then you can set your adapter :)